# error while passing the backend URL as a parameter in template.json file at <set-backend-service base-url>

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy the `APIM` instance by using ARM templates. So I want to pass the backend URL as a parameter. So for that I have added a parameter *"backend_url"* in `parameters.json` file and provided the URL as a value. Also I have added the same parameter in `template.json` file.

In the template.json file at the `<set-backend-service base-url>` element I am passing the parameter as below:

`<set-backend-service base-url=\"(parameters('backend_url'))\"/>`

When I deploy the templates getting

> "Error in element 'set-backend-service' on line 76, column 6: Value is not a valid absolute URL." error.

So please let me know how to pass a parameter in `<set-backend-service base-url>` element while deploying APIM instance using ARM templates.

Comment: <set-backend-service base-url=\"(parameters('backend_url'))\"/>

Comment: Are you trying to define the backend api url policies from the ARM template?

Comment: yes..@SillyJohn

Answer (score 0):

Im doing the same thing at the moment! There are two things to do:

1 - Define the parameter type you are using in the template file

2 - When defining params you need to signify the the start and end of the command using square brackets.

Try this:

```
<set-backend-service base-url=\"[parameters('backend_url')]\"/>
```

MS Resource:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-parameters